# Python: psycopg2.ProgrammingError:INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, psql

I am new to python and I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error. It is telling me I have too many parameters however the table has 8 columns, and I pass it 8 parameters. What is going on? Could this error be misleading and the real problem is the fact that I am trying to pass in values that could be `None` or could be of type `Boolean` using `%s`?

Here is the code snippet

```
        db.cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE temp_clean_mp_duplicates (id bigint, distinctid character varying(255), created timestamp without time zone, email character varying(255), created_exist boolean, email_exist boolean, user_exist boolean, distinct_id_found boolean, CONSTRAINT temp_clean_mp_duplicates_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id));")

        mp_email = None
        email_exist = False
        if "$email" in mp_properties :
            mp_email = mp_properties["$email"]
            email_exist = True

        mp_distinct_id = result["$distinct_id"]
        db_cursor.execute("SELECT u.id, u.email, udm.distinctid, u.sessionId FROM users as u,user_distinctid_map as udm where u.id = udm.user_id and udm.distinctid = %s and lower(email) = lower(%s)", (mp_distinct_id,mp_email,))
        distinct_id_found = True
        if db_cursor.rowcount == 0 :
            distinct_id_found = False

        created = None
        created_exist = False
        if "$created" in mp_properties :
            created = mp_properties["$created"]
            created_exist = True



            db_cursor.execute("SELECT u.id, u.email, u.sessionId FROM users as u where lower(u.email) = lower(%s)", (mp_email,))
            user_id = 0
            user_exist = False
            if db_cursor.rowcount > 0 :
                user_id = db_cursor.fetchone()[0]
                user_exist = True

            db.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO temp_clean_mp_duplicates (id, distinctid, created, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", (user_id, mp_distinct_id, created, mp_email, created_exist, email_exist, user_exist, distinct_id_found))
```

Answer (score 4):

As you found, the issue is indeed the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO temp_clean_mp_duplicates (id, distinctid, created, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", (user_id, mp_distinct_id, created, mp_email, created_exist, email_exist, user_exist, distinct_id_found)
```

You're right that the *table* has eight columns, but you're telling SQL that you're only *setting* four of them with `INSERT INTO temp_clean_mp_duplicates (id, distinctid, created, email)` - the columns in the parenthesis are the ones that it will try to set.

Here's how I think of an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (<target columns>) VALUES (<values on new row>)
```

So if you're trying to set all eight of them, you would need to put all the column names in the parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO temp_clean_mp_duplicates (id, distinctid, created, email, created_exist, email_exist, user_exist, distinct_id_found) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", (user_id, mp_distinct_id, created, mp_email, created_exist, email_exist, user_exist, distinct_id_found)
```

The above query should work.